# Update JavaScript variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables

Please can someone help on how to get the value from jQuery into Javascript?

```
var myTitle = "abctitle";

function showtitle(myVar) {
    myTitle = myVar;    
    alert(myTitle); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(myTitle); //I would like to alert "abctitle"
    myTitle = "changed";
});
```

how can i get the value set in query outside its call in jscript?

Comment: Your code [does alert](http://jsfiddle.net/vuxrevy6/) `abctitle`...? Also, jQuery *is* Javascript.

Comment: i tried the same in JFIDDLE but it didnt work, the second alert outside the JQ didnt get the value set in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right, and does what its supposed to

```js
var myTitle = "abctitle";

var e = document.getElementById('show');
e.onclick = showTitle;

function showTitle(){
 alert(myTitle);   
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert(myTitle); //I would like to alert "abctitle"
    myTitle = "changed";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show">Click Me</button>
```

this will alert myTitle then the new title, showing that 'jquery' can access javascript variables and change them.

Comment: tried with https://jsfiddle.net/kjyqkyma/ but didnt seem to work. all i'm trying to do is amend a variable in JQUERY and refer it outside in JSCRIPT....in your code both the alerts are within the query which would work